# How to fix the TypeError Corresponding to the Conversion between Types in Python3?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am running the following code. Since I am new to python, I am trying to understand why I am getting TypeError and how to fix it. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('SVG')

import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import random
from numpy import array as ar
import math


N = 1000
data = [random.random() for i in range(N)]
x = ar(data)

a = 1.000000
y = (-1.000000) * a * math.log(x)

'''
pyplot.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])
'''

pyplot.xticks([0.1*k for k in range(0,1)])

'''
pyplot.yticks([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0])
'''

pyplot.title('ElegantPDF')
pyplot.xlabel('x')
pyplot.ylabel('PDF(x)')

xminus = [0] * N 
xplus = [0] * N
yminus = [0] * N
yplus = [0] * N


pyplot.plot(x,y, color='blue', linestyle='', marker='o', label='Probability Distribuiton Function')
pyplot.errorbar(x, y, xerr=(xminus, xplus), yerr=(yminus, yplus), ecolor='green', elinewidth=2.0, capsize=20.0)
pyplot.legend(title='The legend')
pyplot.savefig('Elegant.svg')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "ElegantPDF.py", line 15, in 
    y = (-1.000000) * a * math.log(x) TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: probably: `x` is a array and `math.log(x)` expects single number .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error occurs because `math.log()` expects a scalar, or scalar-like arrays.

```
import math
import numpy as np

math.log(np.array([3, 4])) # will fail
math.log(np.array([3]))    # same as math.log(3)
```

If you want to calculate the log of all elements, use `np.log()` instead.

```
np.log(np.array([3, 4]))   # will get array([ 1.09861229,  1.38629436])
```

Comment: I changed the corresponding line to y = (-1.000000) * a * np.log(np.x) and it gives me the following error now: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ElegantPDF.py", line 16, in <module>
    y = (-1.000000) * a * np.log(np.x)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'x'

Comment: @Ashur Nah, you're supposed to just do `np.log(x)`. `x` here is your array, which must be the argument of the function. I just created my arrays on-the-fly, hence why I did `np.array([3, 4])`. This is the same as doing `data = [3, 4]; x = ar(data)` based on your code's syntax.

Comment: The following actually works: np.log(x) since x is already taken to be an array and the line automatically (surprisingly) memorize x to be an array. Thanks Reti43 for giving me a clue about it. Now, I have a new caveat in my plot which is related to my plot settings. I will update you if I could not resolve minor issues of plot settings.

Comment: @Ashur Bonus round. You're missing an equal sign after `xerr` in pyplot.errorbar()`. Similarly, you may also want to add a `linestyle=''` argument there to get rid of any linking lines between the error bars. And you won't actually see the error bars until they have some size bigger than 0. So try `xminus = [1] * N` and `xplus = [2] * N`, for example. Lastly, the `elinewidth` has an extravagant value. Try to tone it down, or completely remove it. For future reference, if you have a follow up issue which isn't related to the original question, it's best to ask a new question altogether.

Answer (score 1):

math.log function expects a scalar as its input parameter while x is an array.

the following line should fix the issue:

```
y = [ math.log(x[i]) for i in range(0,len(x)) ]
```

it is equivalent to `y = np.log(x)`

Comment: This can be simplified to `y = [math.log(i) for i in x]`. However, this will only work for 1d arrays. For multidimensional arrays, each `i` will not be a scalar and you'll run into the same problem, while `np.log()` applies the operation element-wise regardless of shape. Additionally, `np.log()` is vectorised and the operations are much faster than Python-level loops.